# does done() work on ints as well?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in javascript (jquery)

```
function getTopLevelId(gender) {
            var catId = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '{url}'
            dataType: 'html'
        });

        return catId;   //Returns defered object    
    }

function getSelectedCategoryId() {
    return 7; //returns int based on value in an element
};


function mainFuncion(id) {
    if (parseInt(id) === 0) {
        catObj= getTopLevelId(gender);    //Returns defered object       
    }
    else {
        catId = getSelectedCategoryId(id);  //Returns int
        catObj = catId;
    }

    $.when(catObj).done(function(catId) {
            //Doing some stuff and want to use catId as a category id
    }
}
```

My question is about "Doing some stuff" in done(). It **SEEMS** to me like done() is **called** and giving me correct category id even if `catId` is just an int, but is this always true? Or is there any other way that might be "safer" to achieve what I want in mainFunction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If none of the params passed to [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) are unresolved promise objects then the `done` handler is called immediately.

> If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when and it is not a Deferred
>   or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any
>   doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately. The doneCallbacks
>   are passed the original argument. In this case any failCallbacks you
>   might set are never called since the Deferred is never rejected.

```
var a = 7;
$.when(a).done(function (x) {
    console.log('inside', x)
});
console.log('after')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qhh2drq3/), [Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qhh2drq3/2/)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld it might be beneficial to note that while this works this can make for an extremely poor API. Always return the same type - if you do `catObj = $.when(getSelectedCategoryId)` you don't need the `.when` at all.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I don't understand how you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld you have a function that returns a different type every time. Also, the synchronicity changes between executions. Google "releasing zalgo APIs"

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - my issue that I dont want to use synchronius request with async: false in function getTopLevelId(). In that case I could return an int and in that way return same datatypes from that function and getSelectedcategoryId(), but then I would have async:false that is not good either.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld in that case return promise over an int instead in both cases. That's what I was suggesting.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - but how do I do that? Returning the whole html element in getSelectedCategoryId() ?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld `return $.when(yourIntHere)`.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld in the current code it the static part is executing sequentially see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qhh2drq3/4/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum even then the code executing won't be asynchronous... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qhh2drq3/6/ - because the promise is already resolved, but this will provide a uniform api

Comment: Ok, thansk for suggestion Benjamin and for jsfiddles Arun :-)